# Dividing out any constant factor from expression

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

How do I divide out any constants from an expression?

Let's say:

$2A+4B+2C+6 \rightarrow A+2B+C+3$

What's the right command for this?

I have been using `expr==0//Simplify` but that's crude and doesn't really do what I want.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau What if I do not know in principle that 2 will work?

Comment: `FactorTermsList[...][[2]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant, but this could work. Use Factor as follows:

```
In[6]:= expr = 2 A + 4 B + 2 C + 6

Out[6]= 6 + 2 A + 4 B + 2 C

In[7]:= Factor[expr][[2]]

Out[7]= 3 + A + 2 B + C
```

Comment: This does not work as I would like it too, i.e., without knowing in advance if my expression has 2 as common divisor.

Comment: This works with any constant, the '2' in the double bracket refers to the second part of the expression, not to the common factor...

Comment: This is incorrect for any expression having more than 2 factors, e.g.the expression 6 a + 9 a b . Use FactorTermsList, as Daniel already answered.